# Bootstrap 3: Input group in navbar form takes up entire width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So this is what bootstrap's navbar form looks like.

[image]

The default HTML is:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for awesome stuff">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

But I want to join the input and button together like an `input-group`. However, when I try to wrap the input and button around an `input-group`, it ends up occupying the entire width:

[image]

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for awesome stuff">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've read [some solutions for this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950), but I want to **avoid using hacks** like `style: "width: 200px;"`

Any solutions? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you use a wrapper on the input-group and asign a width to that?

Comment: I don't want to manually assign widths (or any sort of "hacks" like that)

Comment: It's not a hack imho. The expected behavior of input-group is to take the full width of its parent element. 

What would be the width or the behavior you would expect from the input-group?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I thought of a minimal way to fix this without modifying the default structure of the navbar form used in the Bootstrap documentation.

Add class `navbar-input-group` to the form

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for awesome stuff">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

CSS (place in media query if necessary):

```
.navbar-input-group {
  font-size: 0px; /*removes whitespace between button and input*/
}

.navbar-input-group input {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-input-group .btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

or SCSS (keeps responsiveness intact):

```
@import "bootstrap-variables";

.navbar-input-group {
  @media (min-width: $screen-sm) {
    font-size: 0px; /*removes whitespace between button and input*/

    input {
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    }
    .btn {
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border-left: 0px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;

    .btn {
      width:100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

*For purposes of clarity, I am targeting descendant elements in the CSS. This is not the most efficient way to target CSS elements. If you like this answer, consider giving the input and button unique class names and targeting them without any descendant selectors in your CSS (read: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)*

Comment: This breaks the responsiveness of the navbar as is.  Please update to include the media query you describe.

Comment: if you add you can also stack several buttons after the input ```.navbar-input-group .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 0;
}```

Answer (score 13):

The fact that your solution takes up the entire width is a good thing. Now use nested rows and columns to define how much space you actually want that search bar to consume.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for awesome stuff">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button></span>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooh. Didn't think of that. Works very well. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I didn't notice OP asked for a solution without manually setting width in CSS. Still, I think this is a good alternative if you don't mind the max-width. It only sets the max-width for the high resolutions, so you keep the normal behavior on tablet and mobile.

1. Add `navbar-searchbox` on `div.input-group`:

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="input-group navbar-searchbox">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

2. Put this in your `.lass` file.

```css
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .navbar-searchbox {
     max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

3. Jump around the room shouting victory!

No need to use rows, and yes that is all the CSS you need. Just works, try it.

Comment: Genius! I didn't do the jumping part (there are people in the room) and it still worked!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to treat the form element as normal, and just fixed its apperance using this CSS rule:

```css
.navbar-form .input-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;

  .form-control,
  .input-group-btn {
     float: left;
  }
}
```