# Adding more components to Bootstrap's navbar causes it to create additional rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap's and I have created a simple navbar:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
             <!-- ADDING SOMETHING HERE -->
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This way, everything works and looks nice. However, if I add anything to my input-group, such as simple glyphicon:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">a2</span>
```

or another textfield:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's surname" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
```

navbar falls to pieces (it splits into three rows). Jsfiddle of a broken navbar added here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5298/. How to stop it from falling apart?

Comment: Looks like your question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893187/bootstrap-3-input-group-in-navbar-form-takes-up-entire-width

Comment: I believe that you're supposed to use one input group per input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I try to modify the class selector in your HTML and add some in CSS as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <li>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <span class="btn btn-default" id="basic-addon2">a2</span>
  </li>
</div>

.input-group li {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here's the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Alicera/y5tm734y/1/)**:

Comment: Actually upgraging bootstrap to the newest version solved this issue for me, but your soultion works as well, so thank you.

Comment: I agree at you for the newest version since I found limited development for web developer in related to bootstrap stylesheet. I'm now also building css framework (progress 40%) but in Indonesian's version :D good luck

Comment: table-cell has the same value as table and inline-block (in bootstrap version when you apply that changes). this destructed the default value, namely, block. when you're using the default, you won't be able to create new style of your own. you should add new css in your link then.